# bash: worker:: command not found on koyeb

Tags: python

I tried to deploy [this bot](https://github.com/Bala7a198/utube)to koyeb but I got this error

```
bash: worker:: command not found
ERROR: failed to determine the run command to launch your application: add a run command in your Service configuration or create a procfile in your git repository.
```

procfile in bot repo

```
worker: python -m bot
```

I have no idea what to do . need detailed help plz !

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> bash: worker:: command not found
> ```

The double `:` colon suggests that
you intended to run e.g. `/usr/bin/worker`
but bash attempted to execute `/usr/bin/worker:`
and found no file by that name.

Revise your command so it has fewer colons.